# postgres regex_replace everything between the third and last forward slash

Tags: regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

I have some URLs within a Postgres table that currently look like this:

```
http://blue.website.com/categoryA/sectionA/title/6534566234
http://yellow.website.com/categoryA/sectionB/title/36476586
http://green.website.com/categoryB/sectionB/title/34646634
```

I am trying to create a regex that can be used to transform the URLs to look like this:

```
http://blue.website.com/6534566234
http://yellow.website.com/36476586
http://green.website.com/34646634
```

I was able to figure out how to use `regex_replace` to replace everything up to the last `/` with nothing:

```
select regexp_replace('http://blue.website.com/categoryA/sectionA/title/6534566234', '^.*/', '')

regexp_replace|
--------------|
6534566234    |
```

However, I'm not sure how to extend this to replace everything between the 3rd `/` and the last `/` with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace with blank (ie "remove") each term separately, using look arounds to target the right parts:

```
select regexp_replace('http://blue.website.com/categoryA/sectionA/title/6534566234', '(?<!/)/[^/]+(?=/)', '', 'g')
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/56908).

The regex `(?<!/)/[^/]+(?=/)` works as follows:

- `/[^/]+` matches a slash followed by non-slashes
- `(?<!/)` the preceding char is not a slash. This prevents matching the part after `//`, which you want to keep
- `(?=/)` requires the following char to be a slash. This prevents matching the final term, which you want to keep

The final parameter `'g'` is the *global* flag - means replace *all* matches (not just the first, as would be the case if this parameter were not specified)